# Can I have one alias for both two real accounts in Google Apps?

Tags: g-suite

Using Google apps business, I need to be able to have a foo@bar.com alias that would be sent to both fred@bar.com and bill@bar.com

Currently, I can't google my way out of this. Any suggestions?

The only thing I can think of is alias foo@bar.com to fred@bar.com. Then setup a filter to forward any mail incoming mail from foo@bar.com to bill@bar.com

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're thinking too hard about this. :)

Create a group "foo" that has both fred and bill  as members. Set access controls on the group as appropriate. By default, I believe it will not allow accounts outside of your domain to email that list.

Comment: Many thanks! It seem I have much more to read up on!